# WooCommerce password strength Change to 6 Char

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, passwords

Like everyone else the password strength gets alittle ridiculous for the customers to handle. so I used the following which REMOVED all password check ("1" is now a valid password)

```
function remove_wc_password_meter() {
wp_dequeue_script( 'wc-password-strength-meter' );
}
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'remove_wc_password_meter', 100 );
```

it is a script based, is there a way not touching the script to make it only require atleast 6 char?

Comment: " is there a way not touching the script.." no thats what the script does

Comment: shouldn't there be a define(strength value); in config or something

Comment: @vico, If you found any solution, please add it as an answer. I'm also searching for the same solution.

Comment: @MansoorkhanCherupuzha answer attached

Comment: try this plugin `WC Password Strength Settings` https://wordpress.org/plugins/wc-password-strength-settings/#description

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What I did was a workaround of this code above which completely removed the password check.

But also attaching a jquery and html password strength script (custom) so the frontend still see a password strength indicator but is turned down to 8 character.

This way you can still prevent users from entering 12 as password but also not do something crazy that will reach the wordpress standard of "safe".

Answer (score 2):

I dont know why you removed

```
 add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_script_data', 'pwd_strength_meter_settings', 20, 2 );

function pwd_strength_meter_settings( $params, $handle  ) {

if( $handle === 'wc-password-strength-meter' ) {

    $params = array_merge( $params, array(

        'min_password_strength' => 2,
        'i18n_password_error' => 'Do not you want to be protected? Make it stronger!',
        'i18n_password_hint' => ' Please make your password <strong>at least 8 characters</strong> long , For more security use a mix of <strong>UPPER</strong> and <strong>lowercase</strong> letters, <strong>numbers</strong>, and <strong>symbols</strong>'
    ) );


}
return $params;

}
```

Comment: or

simply by use this

 * Strength Settings
 * 4 = Strong
 * 3 = Medium (default) 
 * 2 = Also Weak but a little stronger 
 * 1 = Password should be at least Weak
 * 0 = Very Weak / Anything
 */

      add_filter( 'woocommerce_min_password_strength', 
    'misha_change_password_strength' 
 );
 
   function misha_change_password_strength( $strength ) {
  return 4;
   }